# How to add line break without breaking CSS in ul li

Tags: html, css

Following is my HTML

```
<ul>
  <li>
    Jan
  </li>
  <li>
    Feb
  </li>
  <li>
    Mar
  </li>
  <li>
    Apr
  </li>
  <li>
    May
  </li>
  <li>
    Jun<span>1</span>
  </li>
  <li>
    Jul<span><span class="more">30</span>
  </li>
  <li>
    Aug<br>15
  </li>
  <li>
    Sep
  </li>
  <li>
    Oct
  </li>
  <li>
    Nov
  </li>
  <li>
    Dec
  </li>
</ul>
```

And associated css is

```
ul {
  list-style: none;
  li {
    width: 60px;
    line-height: 60px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    color: #019ed5;
    border: 1px solid #019ed5;
    background-color: #FFFFFF;
    cursor: pointer;
    text-align: center;
  }
  span.year{
    color: red;
    display: block;
  }
  span.more-statement{
    position: absolute;
    color:black;
    width:20px;
    height:20px;
    border-radius:50%;
    background:#019ed5;
    font-size:10px;
    line-height:20px;
    color: white;
  }
}
```

This is what I have. I am trying to have 15 right below Aug without any extra spaces or changing the height. Adding br tag is causing css to break the circle. I tried removing the line-height but didn't work. I tried adding span between places where I want line break making display property as block but still have the same behavior.

[image]

Code on Sassmeister: http://sassmeister.com/gist/6c73b40a08d130566cfb

Comment: your css is missing a closing } for the li.

Comment: where? Here http://sassmeister.com/gist/6c73b40a08d130566cfb ? or in the example above?

Answer (score 3):

Below is one method of vertically aligning two lines of text inside your date bubble using `display: table`, `display: table-cell`, and `vertical-align: middle`.

**Screenshot of result:**

[image: screenshot]

**Live Demo:**

```css
ul {
    list-style: none;
    display: table;
}
li {
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: middle;
    width: 60px;
    height: 60px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    color: #019ed5;
    border: 1px solid #019ed5;
    background-color: #FFFFFF;
    cursor: pointer;
    text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<ul>
    <li>Jan<br />15</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Awesome. Thank you. Really appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Remove the line-height attribute. Wrap sep in p tag. You are getting the space because of line-height.

```
<ul>
   <li>
    <p>Sep </p> <span class="year">15 </span>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 1):

You haven't been clear about the display you require, but here's one option:

```css
ul {
  list-style: none;
}
li {
  width: 60px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  color: #019ed5;
  border: 1px solid #019ed5;
  background-color: #FFFFFF;
  cursor: pointer;
  text-align: center;
}
span {display: block; line-height: 30px;}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>
    <span>Jan</span>
    <span>15</span>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: I am trying to get ride of extra line breaks between Jan and 15. It should just be one new line after Jan

Comment: That's not the whole story, though, is it? Because presumably you want the circle to be round? You need to provide the whole picture. :-)

Answer (score 0):

keep the number wrapped in a span then add some css3: `transform: translateY(-40px)` to move that number up

http://jsfiddle.net/8azj0k13/

```
li {
  ...
  span {
    display: block;
    -webkit-transform: translateY(-40px);  /* Chrome, Opera 15+, Safari 3.1+ */
        -ms-transform: translateY(-40px);  /* IE 9 */
            transform: translateY(-40px);  /* Firefox 16+, IE 10+, Opera */
  }
}
```

Comment: Using transform for this is both a bad idea code-wise as well as not producing the result that OP is asking for.

Comment: ah, i misunderstood. i thought by not change the line-height he meant keep it long. indeed the line-height is the problem then